# viewing ip address table of a belkin router

Tags: networking

I have two computers, each with their own respective internal ip address e.g. 192.168.x.xx. Now I also have a belkin router which serves as the gateway, which is at ip address 192.168.2.1:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I can engage the firmware in the router via an http connection to `http://192.168.2.1/`. I am wondering is there a way within the terminal to view the ip address table of the router that does the actual mapping of ip addresses to individual computers. Maybe I want to change one of the internal ip addresses, make it static, etc. Can this be accomplished within the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all address on LAN using a command

```
sudo arp-scan -l
```

Maybe you need to install arp-scan. Output will be like this

```
xxxxx@xxxxx ~ $ sudo arp-scan -l
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6c:62:6d:ce:71:0c   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 00:26:18:e4:a5:a4   ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6c:62:6d:ce:84:8b   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 00:30:4f:18:b1:52   PLANET Technology Corporation
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 00:25:22:e4:31:29   ASRock Incorporation
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6c:62:6d:ce:84:93   Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 74:d4:35:0a:6d:38   (Unknown)
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 00:1f:d0:67:40:65   GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
```

Based on this you can figured which pc have which ip.

Comment: This arp-scan doesn't tell me anything different than ifconfig or routes utilities do.

Comment: @JohnMerlino `ifconfig` tell you about interfaces on pc. `routes` tell you about route on your pc. `arp-scan` send arp ping to your lan and get mac|ip address pair. Also you can use `sudo netdiscover -r 192.168.2.0/24`, one more nice tool.